Maya Python: How to make a cube fall on a plane with uplifts and PITS, make the bottom of the cube fit the inclined angle of the curved surface
the result i want
How to use PythonScript to make this in Maya2022.
I tried to use raycast to get point under the cube usingOpenMaya.MFnMesh.closestIntersection() in order to fall the cube at the position of point.
But editor just give a RuntimeError at this line of codehit, _, hit_point, _ = mesh_fn.closestIntersection(ray_source, ray_direction, OpenMaya.MSpace.kWorld, 100, False)without any extra infos.
Here is my code in total
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.api.OpenMaya as OpenMaya

def ray_intersects_object(ray_start, ray_direction, object_name):
    selection_list = OpenMaya.MSelectionList()
    selection_list.add(object_name)
    dag_path = selection_list.getDagPath(0)
    mesh_fn = OpenMaya.MFnMesh(dag_path)
    # ray_source = OpenMaya.MFloatPoint(ray_start[0], ray_start[1], ray_start[2])
    ray_source = OpenMaya.MFloatPoint(0., 0., 0.)
    ray_direction = OpenMaya.MFloatVector(ray_direction[0], ray_direction[1], ray_direction[2])
    v = OpenMaya.MFloatVector(0.,1.,0.)
    hit_point = OpenMaya.MFloatPoint()
    hit, _, hit_point, _ = mesh_fn.closestIntersection(ray_source, ray_direction, OpenMaya.MSpace.kWorld, 100, False)
    if hit:
        return True, [hit_point.x, hit_point.y, hit_point.z]
    else:
        return False, None
start_point = (0, 10, 0)
direction = (0, 1, 0)
object_to_check = 'ground'  # Replace with the name of your object in Maya
ray_intersects_object(start_point, direction, object_to_check)


there is absolutely an object named "ground" in maya

If I execute your code I clearly see the problem: # Error: ValueError: file <maya console> line 14: too many values to unpack (expected 4).
And if I check this line I can see that the result of the closestIntersection() method returns an set with 6 values: (maya.api.OpenMaya.MFloatPoint(0, 0, 0, 1), -0.0, 44, 1, 0.0, 0.0) whereas you only unpack 4. Fix this and your code should work.
